# Equivalent of R rbind.fill in Python Pandas

Tags: python, r, pandas

R's plyr function has:
rbind.fill() which is a way to append data frames with unequal number of columns.

Is there a similar function for python / pandas DataFrame?

Comment: Yes it does. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are looking for the function `concat`:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['a','b'],'col2':[33,44]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col3':['dog'],'col2':[32], 'col4':[1]})

In [8]: pd.concat([df1, df2])
Out[8]: 
  col1  col2 col3  col4
0    a    33  NaN   NaN
1    b    44  NaN   NaN
0  NaN    32  dog     1
```